# Searching GridView

Tags: linq, gridview, entitydatasource

I am trying to make searchable GridView.  it's DataSource is EntityDataSource.  I have one textbox and a button. The problem is I need to use Linq to access the data.  I don't really have any code yet, because I'm net at Linq and not sure what I'm doing. Can anyone help me?

Comment: If I am not wrong, On click of button you want to search for the data entered in your textbox from the gridview datasource?

Comment: Yes @KarthikGanesan I want to be enter a search item in the textbox, then when the button is clicked the records that match the search box will be displayed in the gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you to get started

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Customer> lstCust = new List<Customer>();
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Customer c = new Customer();
                c.FName = "FistName " + i.ToString();
                lstCust.Add(c);
            }
            Session["Data"] = lstCust;
            GridView1.DataSource = lstCust;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchText = TextBox1.Text;
        List<Customer> lstCustSearch = new List<Customer>();
        List<Customer> lstCust = new List<Customer>();
        lstCust = Session["Data"] as List<Customer>;

        lstCustSearch = (from data in lstCust
                         where data.FName.Contains(searchText)
                         select data).ToList();
        GridView1.DataSource = lstCustSearch;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
}
```

sorry for the coding convention. just came up with this sample